# I'm not calling $apply explicitly but still get Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress

Tags: angularjs

In a angular factory I have a method to create a new item, which has a connection to a user and a price to add to that users "items" array (like a shopping cart). So I have to see if the user is present in my the local users array if not then on the server and if not then create the user.

Code looks like this:

```
var saveItem = function (item) {
    var user = filterUserById(item.ownerId);

    if (user) {
        user.createItem(item);
    } else {
        repository.getUserById(item.ownerId).then(
        function (serverUser) {
            var userViewModel = repository.getUserViewModel(serverUser);
            userViewModel.createItem(item);
            users.push(userViewModel);
        }
        , function () {
            user = {
                id: item.ownerId,
                items: [
                    createItemDto(item)
                ]
            };

            repository.createUser({ id: user.id }, user);
            users.push(repository.getUserViewModel(user));
        });
    }
};
```

No matter which of the "cases" occurs (user was found localy, on the server or was created and added) I get an error:

> Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.18/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply

I recon this may have to do with the fact that I'm using resources in my repository, but I don't think resource should (since it's a part of angular..). Here's the user.createItem method, code:

```
user.createItem = function (item) {
    var resource = userResource
        , itemDto = createItemDto(item)
        , command = [{
        Type: 'add',
        Name: 'items',
        Value: itemDto
    }];
    resource.createItem({ id: item.ownerId }, command);

    this.items.push(itemDto);
};
```

Y U NO WERK!? PLS HLP! :'(

P.S. I don't have any explicit calls to apply, compile or digest anywhere in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem! I had put a small code line to set focus on the correct input after the item was added and form was emptied. This consisted of a

```
$('selector').focus();
```

This was colliding with digest cycle... Solution:

```
$timeout($('selector').focus());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your call to `user.createItem(item)` in a `$timeout` function:

```
$timeout(function() {
  user.createItem(item);
}, 0);
```

It's possible you could be triggering some other call to `$scope.$apply()` some other way.

Alternatively, try using `$scope.$evalAsync(function())`

Here's some good info: [inprog](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog)

Comment: Thank you for good tips. I have made it a rule for myself never to trigger apply explicitly. I don't trigger it in this solution any where. There is ofc the possibility that my code somehow implicitly trigger apply that I don't know of, this seems illogical 'cos if so, that would be a angular method itself that was incompatible... but I might ofc have used some part of angular in a way that it is not intended... I Will try your tips.